# Time series interpolation adding non events

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I am on a steep learning curve with R and could really do with some pointers on how to go about ranking and interpolating a time series. Some outputs will be linked to the time, some, such as the events - will need filling as blank. Ultimately I want to move onto a binomial regression model against various variables linked to time/date

Data were observed over three months - so day of year (doy) vary with further column data

essentially need to fill in the non events - and add tied data

A sample of the data looks like this

```
    doy time    start   end    blk  Age Event

    186 04:17   04:00   07:00   1   13  1
    186 04:22   04:00   07:00   1   13  1
    186 04:23   04:00   07:00   1   13  1
    186 04:25   04:00   07:00   1   7   1
    186 04:27   04:00   07:00   1   13  1
    186 04:28   04:00   07:00   1   13  1
```

And I want the end result (with a 5min example) to look like this

```
    doy time        start   end   blk   Age Event
    186 04:00-04:05 04:00   07:00   1   13  0
    186 04:05-04:10 04:00   07:00   1   13  0
    186 04:10-04:15 04:00   07:00   1   13  0
    186 04:15-04:20 04:00   07:00   1   13  1
    186 04:20-04:25 04:00   07:00   1   13  2
    186 04:25-04:30 04:00   07:00   1   13  3
```

It would be great to get some pointers on a code that will get me going, that I can then adapt to include the rest of the data

Comment: I don't really follow your question, but you may find the survival package useful if you are aiming to perform survival analyses. This allows you to perform lexis expansion of data, similar to the stsplit function in Stata.

Comment: Thanks user2633645 - The event is a 'feed' (seabirds).. Provisioning rate rather than survival. Will want to model with factors such as time/tide/climate/weather/chick age and so on.

Comment: I'm not great at this, but survival analysis doesn't have to be time to death (or removal from set), it can also be rate of event with multiple events occurring per individual in the data set. I would have thought that something like feeding rate would be better modelled as poisson distribution (time to event) than binomial (happened/didn't happen).

Comment: Great - I will explore that root. Have started looking along the binomial path as the data will not normalise, so 'happened/didn't happen' seemed a sensible way to look at it. Thanks again user2633645

Comment: Convert to `POSIXct` for the date and times. Then create an "event.group" variable with `cut.POSIXct` with breaks= `seq.POSIXct(min(time), max(time), by="5 min")`. Then aggregate.